# Design decision to memorize already constructed instances/references

Tags: c#, design, design-patterns, wpf

I am working in WPF application and in need of a best design decision for one scenario. Basically, I am reading a .net assembly to extract the types and properties and mapping it to my own created custom classes to hold that data to make it serializable. While extracting, i required a way not to read the same type again if it is encountered as part of some property type.

**Problem**

I want a way to remember all the extracted types and when they appear again use the same reference from some in-memory storage.

Now i can think of a solution using Cache or Factory design pattern. But need an expert verdict to coup with this situation.

Currently, i have designed below class to hold and memorize the references.

```
public abstract class Factory<S, T> : IFactory<S, T>
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<S, T> Cache = new Dictionary<S, T>();

    public T Create(S source)
    {
        if (!Cache.ContainsKey(source))
        {
            Cache.Add(source, CreateInstance(source));
        }
        return Cache[source];
    }

    protected abstract T CreateInstance(S source);
}
```

Comment: Why static cache?

Comment: To keep the references available across whole application.

Comment: This code looks smelly that is why i asked here to know about the best technique to use in this case.

Comment: I think any implementation would be OK as long as you always reference it via injected interface.

Comment: Static member raises suspicion because it is not needed if a class is a single instance injected into clients.

Comment: Yet there must be some best practices and adopted way(s) of doing similar things.

Comment: Your code is fine, just replace static member with an instance one, introduce thread safety, use atomic dictionary operations. Also, cover each factory with Unit tests, because you obviously have not done this yet.

Comment: To do this easier consider splitting factory and it's cache and test them separately. Cached factory can just be a decorator of a normal one.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but the reason why I kept it static was on purpose, so that wherever i create concrete factory, i get the same values everywhere. If for instance i kept it non-static then i have to inject factory dependency wherever i am extracting metadata. I hope i have managed to elaborate my point here.

Comment: And what do you mean by atomic dictionary operations and how to separate factory from cache, give example code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50264/discussion-between-furqan-safdar-and-basilevs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excluding descendants of Factory writing to the same storage (making return value undeterministic), your approach would work fine for single-threaded application not covered with Unit tests and implementing a monolith architecture.

I suggest:

- avoid using global state (Singleton or static member)
- inject factory interface in clients to be able to replace implementation (in particular, this would make easier to disable memoization and test clients)
- introduce thread safety
- separate concerns of caching and creation
- cover cache and factories with separate Unit tests
- test performance with and without memoization

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

/// Generic factory interface. Consider using Func<S,T> instead
public interface IFactory<S, T> {
  T Create(S source);
}

/// Memoization decorator
public sealed class MemoizedFactory<S, T> : IFactory<S, T> {
    private readonly IFactory<S, T> toDecorate;
    // Accessed from different threads
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<S, T> cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<S, T>();
    public MemoizedFactory(IFactory<S, T> toDecorate) {
       this.toDecorate = toDecorate;
    }
    public T Create(S source) {
       return cache.GetOrAdd(source, toDecorate.Create);
    }
}

public sealed class PrefixFactory: IFactory<String, String>  {
       public int invocationCount = 0;
       public String Create(String source) {
           invocationCount++;
           return "prefix" + source;
       }
}

class TestClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var prefixFactory = new PrefixFactory();
            var memoizedFactory = new MemoizedFactory<String, String>(prefixFactory);
            Trace.Assert(memoizedFactory.Create("test") == "prefixtest");
            Trace.Assert(prefixFactory.invocationCount == 1);
            Trace.Assert(memoizedFactory.Create("test") == "prefixtest");
            Trace.Assert(prefixFactory.invocationCount == 1);
            Trace.Assert(memoizedFactory.Create("test2") == "prefixtest2");
            Trace.Assert(prefixFactory.invocationCount == 2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Liked the thread-safe technique.

Comment: Read docs before using GetOrAdd - it multistarts,  fine for your use, but not for disposables.

Comment: Noticed that GetOrAdd calling multiple times for same source key, resulting in creating further new target instances. What is the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: I've explicitly stated this in previous comment. Usually this does not need fixing, as collisions will occur only very rarely. Do you need to dispose extra instances before their garbage collection?

Comment: I simply do not want to create further instances if one already created and exists.

Comment: Then you are safe. Concurrent access will not happen often. You can observe it in debugger using breakpoints and steps, but you won't see them in production.